# Python pandas dataframe - extract a list stored in a specific cell, change a value in that list, put back the modified list in that cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I'm trying to extract a list stored in a specific cell, change a value in that list, put back the modified list in that cell with python pandas package.

Here's part of my code:

```
index_a = 1

temp_list = []
# Extract the list from the cell index_a, mycolumn
temp_list = df.loc[index_a,  'mycolumn']
# add mynumber to the element 5 of that list
temp_list[4] = temp_list[4] + mynumber
# put back the modified list in the original cell index_a, mycolumn
df.at[index_a,  'mycolumn'] = temp_list

temp_list = []
# Extract the list from the cell index_a, mynextcolumn
temp_list = df.loc[index_a,  'mynextcolumn']
# add myothernumber to the element 5 of that list
temp_list[4] = temp_list[4] + myothernumber
# put back the modified list in the original cell index_a, mycolumn
df.at[index_a,  'mynextcolumn'] = temp_list
```

The problem is that all the row end up with the same list and all the list are identical.
ex:

```
index    mycolumn    mynextcolumn
  0    [0,4,0,0,6]   [0,4,0,0,6]
  1    [0,4,0,0,6]   [0,4,0,0,6]
  2    [0,4,0,0,6]   [0,4,0,0,6]
```

What i'm suposed to have:

```
index    mycolumn    mynextcolumn
  0    [1,2,3,4,5]   [6,7,8,9,0]
  1    [0,0,1,1,2]   [0,4,0,0,6]
  2    [0,1,2,3,4]   [5,6,7,8,9]
```

It seems like the last use of "temp_list" replace all the list in my df, like in that case every list have been changed for [0,4,0,0,6] at the end even if i specified the cell i wanted to be changed.

In resume, how can i extract a list from a specific df cell based on the index and column name, change a value in that list and put that modified list back in the original cell.

Thanks for your time, Vincent

Comment: Please show what's the df before making change.

Comment: The code you post seems to work as expected on pandas 2.0.3. I used the data frame example `df = pd.DataFrame({'mycolumn': [[1,2,3,4,5], [0,0,1,1,2], [0,1,2,3,4]], 'mynextcolumn': [[6,7,8,9,0], [0,4,0,0,6], [5,6,7,8,9]]})` with `mynumber = 1`, `myothernumber = 2`. Could there be other lines of code that change the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[1,2], [3,4]], 'col2': [[5,6], [7,8]]})
df.loc[1, 'col1'][1] += 50
print(df)
      col1    col2
0   [1, 2]  [5, 6]
1  [3, 54]  [7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Update a cell (value) with `at` or `loc`.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'mycolumn': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
    'mynextcolumn': [[6, 7, 8, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 0, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# at
df.at[0, 'mycolumn'][-1] += 5
df.at[0, 'mynextcolumn'][4] += 5
# loc
# df.loc[0, 'mycolumn'][-1] += 5
# df.loc[0, 'mynextcolumn'][4] += 5
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
           mycolumn     mynextcolumn                                           
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]<=  [6, 7, 8, 9, 5]<=                                
1   [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]    [0, 4, 0, 0, 6]
2   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a list to a name actually assigns a reference to the list, so you do not need to "put back the list" in the dataframe. In addition, since Python is a dynamic language, you do not need to "declare" `temp_list` by initializing it to an empty list before assigning it to the element of interest.

Check this example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3] # assign a to a list in memory                                                  
b = a # give this list an additional name, b                                                  
b[1] = 99 # access list via name b, and change a value                                        
a = b # this does nothing, as both point to the same list                                     
b = [0, 0, 0] # now b points to a new list                                                    
print(a) # a still points to the original list
```

If you follow the order of the assignments of `temp_list` in your code, I'm sure you'll figure out why you end up with the same list all over.

Instead, you can do something as simple as

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[i for i in range(3)] for i in range(5)] for j in range(3)])              
df.columns = [f"col{i}" for i in range(5)]                                                    
print(df)                                                                                     
                                                                                              
temp = df.at[1, "col1"]                                                                       
temp[2] = temp[2] + 999                                                                       
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a complicated loop, just use the fact that lists are mutable:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mycolumn': [[1,2,3,4,5],
                                [0,0,1,1,2],
                                [0,1,2,3,4]],
                   'mynextcolumn': [[6,7,8,9,0],
                                    [0,4,0,0,6],
                                    [5,6,7,8,9]]})

for col in ['mycolumn', 'mynextcolumn']:
    for lst in df[col]:
        lst[4] += 1
```

Or with two loops:

```
for lst in df['mycolumn']:
    lst[4] += 1
for lst in df['mynextcolumn']:
    lst[4] += 1
```

Input:

```
          mycolumn     mynextcolumn
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
1  [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]  [0, 4, 0, 0, 6]
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Output:

```
          mycolumn      mynextcolumn
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]   [6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
1  [0, 0, 1, 1, 3]   [0, 4, 0, 0, 7]
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]  [5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
```